# BigQuery permissions for ALTER TABLE differ from EDIT SCHEMA

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We're trying to create a custom role in GCP that can execute DDL to create/modify datasets and tables but does not have data visibility (i.e. cannot select data from tables).

We've created a custom role with the following permissions:

```
bigquery.datasets.create
bigquery.datasets.update
bigquery.datasets.delete
bigquery.datasets.get 
bigquery.tables.create
bigquery.tables.update
bigquery.tables.delete
bigquery.tables.get
bigquery.tables.list
bigquery.jobs.create
bigquery.config.get
```

We've found that a user with this custom role:

- CAN add a column to an existing table through "EDIT SCHEMA" in the BigQuery web UI.
- CANNOT add a column using ALTER TABLE in the BigQuery web UI.
  Error message: "Access Denied: User does not have permission to query table..."

These are equivalent tasks so it's not clear why the permissions required should differ.
Why does ALTER TABLE require query permission??

```
ALTER TABLE project.dataset.tablename
ADD COLUMN columnname;
```